# How hide() div with ul list if all <li> have properties display: none;

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my little search. I have 6 different Categories, like this below. When I trying to find something, I want that box with categories where there is no any result, will be hidden - all `li` have properties `display: none`.

```
<div class="category">
    <h4>Cars</h4>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Ford</li>
        <li>Opel</li>
        <li>Volkswagen</li>
        <li>Saab</li>
        <li>BMW</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

See on [GitHub](https://dankudyba.github.io/search/)

Comment: So you want to hide .category in case that all li element are with display: none? 
Can you please explain better the problem?

Comment: I have 6 categories, like this above, and I use input for serach in this ul list. I want hide this catogories that don't have any result (so all li have display:none). 

This project on github:  https://dankudyba.github.io/search/

Comment: Your question should include what you've already tried. Your github shows some functionality, however your question includes just a simple HTML snippet. For example, in your github, if a category were to be hidden, it would never show again because you didn't mention this aspect.

Comment: You have right, all this answere are correct, but I forget about this aspect. It should be show again when I delete a few letter.

Comment: @dankudyba that's already fixed in the answer below by using `.show()`

Comment: Thank everyone so much! ;)

Answer (score 3):

`.filter()` your `$(".category")` by returning only the ones who's all `li`s are hidden

http://api.jquery.com/filter/
https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

```js
$(".category").show().filter(function() {
  return ! $(this).find("li:visible").length;
}).hide();
```

---

#### Full-featured example in action:

```js
var $cat = $('.category');
var $li = $cat.find('li');

$('#box').on("input", function() {

  var inputValue = $.trim(this.value); // Trim values!
  var rgx = new RegExp(inputValue, "i"); // Case insensitive

  // Handle LI elements visibility first
  $li.show().filter(function() {
    return ! rgx.test($(this).text())
  }).hide();

  // Than handle .category wrappers
  $cat.show().filter(function() {
    return ! $(this).find("li:visible").length;
  }).hide();

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h3 class="text-center main-header">What do you need?</h3>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="box">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row box-wrapper">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 box">
      <div class="category">
        <h4>Cars</h4>
        <ul class="list">
          <li style="">Ford</li>
          <li style="">Opel</li>
          <li style="">Volkswagen</li>
          <li style="">Saab</li>
          <li style="">BMW</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 box">
      <div class="category">
        <h4>Clothes</h4>
        <ul class="list">
          <li style="">Shirt</li>
          <li style="">Blouse</li>
          <li style="">Trousers</li>
          <li style="">Dress</li>
          <li style="">T-shirt</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 box">
      <div class="category">
        <h4>Phones</h4>
        <ul class="list">
          <li style="">Iphone</li>
          <li style="">Samsung</li>
          <li style="">Xaomi</li>
          <li style="">Huawei</li>
          <li style="">Nokia</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 box">
      <div class="category">
        <h4>Software</h4>
        <ul class="list">
          <li style="">Visual Studio Code</li>
          <li style="">Brackets</li>
          <li style="">Atom</li>
          <li style="">Notepad++</li>
          <li style="">Sublime Text</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 box">
      <div class="category">
        <h4>Cameras</h4>
        <ul class="list">
          <li style="">Sony</li>
          <li style="">Canon</li>
          <li style="">Samsung</li>
          <li style="">Panasonic</li>
          <li style="">Nikon</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 box">
      <div class="category">
        <h4>Home</h4>
        <ul class="list">
          <li style="">Tools</li>
          <li style="">Furniture</li>
          <li style="">Equipment</li>
          <li style="">Pets</li>
          <li style="">Other</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hide the div in case all `li` have property of `display : none` you can use the following code :

```
var li = $(".list li").css({'display' : 'none'})
if(li){
   $(".category").css({'visibility' : 'hidden'})
} else {
   $(".category").css({'display' : 'none'})
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Where is your else statement?

Comment: He can just make that on his own. I'm just showing a snippet on how he can achieve what he's asking :) @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: What I mean is that your `//or` should be `} else {`. makes it easier for other to read your code.

Comment: Idev, do you know what's stored inside `li`?